# Category URL Key Field showing as disabled non editable Magento 2.2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.3

On my Magento 2.2.3 store, I'm adding new categories. But it seems that on all new, but also the old existing categories. I'm unable to change the URL Key under the 'Search Engine optimization' tab.

The URL is shown, but it's greyed out and the input field is disabled. my website has 4 stores.

Anyone can suggest this. I am not getting any solution.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After lots of R&D and step by step debug in the code I have found the solution. It was the Plazma theme module issue. in the file view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml I have found the code below and I have commented this.

```
<item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
 <item name="disabled" xsi:type="string">${ $.provider }:data.use_default.url_key</item>
</item>
```

Now everything working fine.

Comment: In my case it was `app/code/Plazathemes/Override/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml`

Answer (score 0):

There are ways you can try to debug this issue:

> 1. Check if you are editing the **category** for the specific **Store View**
> 2. Go to **Store→Configuration→Catalog→Catalog→Search Engine Optimization** and check if **Create Permanent Redirect for URLs if URL Key Changed** is set to **YES**

Comment: I have already checked both ways and all are set as you said. category URL is also not editable with store view also

Comment: can you switch to other store view? and check if it will work

Comment: didn't work already checked not getting why it is showing disable in html input filed